# Dialogflow system entity is missing for Thai language

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

When i am trying to add **@sys.number-sequence** for Thai language, its not available but when i am checking in English language its available.

[image: Thai language sequence not available screenshot]

[image: English language sequence available screenshot]

How can i check the number sequence in Thai language, if i have to create that as custom entity also i don't have idea how to create sequence as custom entity field.

Please provide me any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue in other languages. Your best bet will be to create custom entity with a regexp value like so (mark the Regexp entity checkbox)

[image]

After you saved your entity, enter some training phrases to match your new entity and assign the parameter a name.

You can create a webhook with the coding language of your preference that catches the parameter with that name and checks it with something like regex that it is indeed a sequence of characters